# Mongoose Node - How can I res.send my error to client from mongoose error event handler?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

How can I send the error to my client from:

```
mongoose.connection.on('error', function(err, resp){
   //cant do res.send() here
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why would you do this?

Comment: because if there is a mongoose err such as connection error for example, I need to notify the client, so the user know there is an issue.

Comment: You can print the error log on the server side. This is a server error, no need to send it to the client. If the MongoDB connection established fails, you can end the Node process using `process.exit(1);`

Comment: but then the user would not understand why app isnt working if i just log errors

Answer (score 0):

A good way would be to create a separate endpoint like `server-stat` or `health` then expose that either by `Server Sent Event` or simple `Rest Api`.

In case of rest api - frontend person can use polling to get updated status within a certian time interval (i.e. 1min)

In case of Server Sent Event, you can define the interval timing from the backend and frontend person can utilize `EventSource` to use that.

Lets say you want to implement a rest api.

```
let db;

mongoose.connection.on('error', function(err, client){
   if(!err) db = client.db("<YOUR-DB>");
});
```

Then check on the rest api

```
const app = express();

app.get("/health", (req, res) => {
  if (db?.serverConfig?.isConnected()) {   
    return res.send({ mongoStatus: true});
  }
  return res.send({ mongoStatus: false});
});
```